# show that the number is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x,y>2$ and $\in\mathbb{N}$. Show,that if $x^2+y^2-1$ is divided by $x+y-1$, then $x+y-1$ isn't prime.

$$x^2+y^2-1=(x+y)^2-1-2xy=(x+y-1)(x+y+1)-2xy$$
Thefore, $2xy=k(x+y-1), k\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Some steps more: if $x+y-1$ is even, then it's nothing to talk about, so let $x+y-1$ is odd. Then $xy=k'(x+y-1), k'\in\mathbb{N}$, moreover, $x$ and $y$ are both even or both odd. And...I stuck.

Comment: How can $(x+y-1)$ divide $2xy$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime. If $p$ divides a product, $p\mid abc$, then $p$ divides one of the factors, $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ or $p\mid c$ (Euclid's lemma).

Now if $x+y-1$ were prime ...

> ... it would divide $2,\; x$, or $y$. But it is greater than all of the three.

Comment: then it divides $x$ or $y$, then $x$ or $y$ isn't prime...and i don't reach any contrаdiction. /:

Comment: Since $x,y \geqslant 2$, can you have $(x+y-1) \leqslant x$?

Comment: No, I can't. It's greater than both $x$ and $y$...

Comment: I get it! Thanks!